# Passando um valor do body de um modal para uma função PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, modal

Boa noite,

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um modal dentro de um sistema, o que eu preciso fazer e não estou conseguindo é passar os valores que eu leio no javascript para uma função do PHP para no caso "deletar" o que eu necessito, se alguém puder por favor me ajudar, eu sou novo em desenvolvimento e estou lutando para conseguir continuar aprendendo, muito obrigado mesmo, segue os códigos que estou utilizando:

Aqui é a minha função:

```
<?php 

    function paraProd($id,$maquina){

            $id = $_POST ['id'];
            $maquina = $_POST ['maquina'];

            //  Declara os valores de sessão globais a uma variável!
            $local = $_SESSION['hostname'];
            $user = $_SESSION['idUsuario']; 

            //  Chama função de conexão com banco de dados!

            $conn = DBConnect();

            //  Faz as alterações de UPDATE nas tabelas do banco de dados!

            $sql = "DELETE FROM supervisorio.producao_inj WHERE maquina = '$maquina'";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                  echo "Record deleted successfully";
                } else {
                  echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                }



    }
```

Aqui é o modal da onde eu quero enviar os dados para a função do PHP:

```
function modalAceita(id,maquina,lote,produto){

            $.ajax({
            url:"functions.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: {id:id,maquina:maquina,lote:lote,produto:produto},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#modal4').find('.modal-body').html('Carregando...');
                $('#modal4').modal('show');
            },
            success:function() {
                $('#modal').modal('hide');
                $('#modal4').find('.modal-title').html("<strong>INJETORA "+id+"</strong>");
                $('#modal4').find('.modal-body').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Tem certeza de parar a Produção?</div><div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Maquina: <label>'+maquina+'</label><br/>Produto: <label>'+produto+'</label><br/>Lote: <label>'+lote+'</label><br/></div><div class="row justify-content-md-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="<?php paraProd('+id+','+maquina+');?>" data-dismiss="modal">Salvar mudanças</button></div>');
                $('#modal4').modal('show');
            }
        });

}
```

Tenho certeza que estou fazendo da forma errada, porém não encontrei em lugar algum uma solução, me desculpem se postei da maneira errada tb minha pergunta, porém sou novo nessa jornada, muito obrigado desde já a quem puder me ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Único problema que eu vejo é que sua função paraProd() não esta sendo chamada, se é para remover um registro de determinada tabela, ao invés de fazer isso dentro do functions.php você poderia criar um arquivo exclusivo para deletar os registro desta tabela.

ex:

cria um arquivo chamado delete_table.php (ai chama esse arquivo no ajax)

no incio do arquivo faz uma validação de isset

if(isset($_POST['id])){

// aqui vc faz a rotina de deletar o registro ou então chama sua função paraProd()

}